# how can i find the sum of multidimensional array which makes the user input the rows and columns in a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number of rows/columns in matrix : ");    //rows and columns in matrix must be same.
int rows = scanner.nextInt();
int columns = rows;
int[][] matrix = new int[rows][rows];

System.out.println("Enter the elements in matrix :");
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What, exactly, do you find hard to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `sum` variable which adds up the elements in the two D array like so:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
        sum += matrix[i][j];
    }
}
System.out.print("The sum is :");
System.out.println(sum); //Simply for clarity
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java8

```
long sum = Arrays.stream(matrix).flatMapToInt(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr)).sum();
```